# Expand to the largest contained "positioned" block?

Tags: css

In a container can you *in any way* position two blocks *above each other* (eg absolute) and make the container expand to the size/height of the largest one?

If using `position: absolute` the container does not expand to the size of the positioned element.

*Is there any way to get this effect with CSS?*

---

Illustrative (defunct) example:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="foo">foo</div>
    <div class="bar">bar</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
}
.foo{
    height: 40px;
}
.bar{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qjFR9/

I'd like to position `.bar` over `.foo` (position `.bar` as if there was no `.foo`) and `.wrap` should be the height of the largest child.

Comment: Sorry, not clear with your explanation. Any example or screenshot explaining this situation might help.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure CSS by the very nature of how `position: absolute` works -- easy with JS, but do you have a use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the width of the container is fixed a solution like this works:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="foo"><div class="inner">foo</div></div>
    <div class="bar"><div class="inner">bar</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrap,
.wrap .inner{
    width: 300px;
}
.wrap > div{
    float: left;
    width: 0;
}

/* test: .wrap expands to fit the .inner content */
.bar > .inner{
    height: 60px;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qjFR9/1/).

But this doesn't work with non-fixed width wrappers.

Is there a better way?